# Linking two blocks

Tags: nxt

I am in a contest and would like to use one Mindstorm block to control another.  I am new at this.  We are in invention section of the contest and trying to develop a pipe laying machine. Basically I need to know if they can be linked along with a way to do it.

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate - as far as I know the principle is slightly different for EV3s. If using LeJOS, you can connect the EV3s via USB and make one the slave and the other the master. I'm not sure how to do this with the standard Mindstorms software though, which is likely what is used in this contest (I assume it is the FLL :) ).

Comment: @PhilB. It's tagged [tag:nxt] there's nothing else to say that this is using EV3s.

Comment: I hadn't seen the tag - you're absolutely right, it is tagged as #nxt. So yes, looks like a duplicate.